# Imagick annotateImage not showing correctly japanese text

Tags: php, imagick

I'm trying to print japanese text to the image.
My code:

```
$text = // some japanese text

$imagick = new IMagick();
// $imagick implementation

$imagickDraw = new ImagickDraw();
$imagickDraw->setFontSize(12);

$textFontMetrics = $imagick->queryFontMetrics($imagickDraw, $text);
$imagick->annotateImage($imagickDraw, ($imageWidth - $textFontMetrics['textWidth']) / 2, $imageHeight * 0.5, 0, $text);

// save imageBlob
```

When i check my generated image, instead of normal japanese text i just see '??'. Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty sure this is a font related issue. Make sure you have a font capable of displaying Japanese characters, copy that font to your script's directory, and add the following:

```
$draw->setFont('fonts-japanese-gothic.ttf');
```

Where `fonts-japanese-gothic.ttf` is the name of your font. I tested it out on my local machine and that did the trick.

Comment: can you share some japanese font?

Comment: @pacification you can search google for the font mentioned in my answer, this is the [first result](https://github.com/blagarde/midori).